# Take a screenshot on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone

Is there a way to take a screenshot of the Windows Phone 7? On the iPhone you can press the square button and the power button at the same time to take a screenshot, is there an equivalent action on WP7?

I am using a real phone and not the emulator. This is an easy task on the emulator, but I have collected some data via GPS, which is not available in the emulator.

Comment: you mean a real phone not the emulator?

Comment: if it's your own app and you want to do a screenshot, you can just do a writeable bitmap to screen scrape your app.

Comment: Yes, I am using the phone, not the emulator. How would you do a writeable bitmap? Could you point me in the right direction with a few lines of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No solution for the device but for the emulator you have this tool that takes "marketplace-compatible" screenshoots: http://www.innovativetechguy.com/?p=13

It would be nice to have this feature on the phone.

Answer (score 4):

As kP and Mattheiu advise this isn't possible via hardware keys and you can still get dev screenys if that's your need using the tool recommended here.

If you did want to build a function to do this in to your app for some reason, possibly a hidden function of some kind, it can be done. This post will demonstrate.

[Mark Arteaga - Screen Capture on Windows Phone 7](http://blog.markarteaga.com/ScreenCaptureOnWindowsPhone7.aspx)

Comment: code on this page worked for me; probably best alternative until msft employs better.

Answer (score 3):

You can't take a screenshot on the device at itself, at the moment. However, if you're running on the emulator, you can use the snipping tool built into Windows 7. In the start menu, type in 'snip' and click on the Snipping Tool program. If you're doing this for screenshots that will be added to the marketplace, make sure you don't include any of the emulator chrome.

Comment: this would be how I would go about it...+1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I believe this to be impossible for two reasons. First: there is no real multitasking on wp7. So there is no way any screenshot-app can take a snapshot of any other running app. Second: AFAIK every app runs in its own sandbox.

If there is a way, please correct me here.

Comment: "there is no real multitasking on wp7" not true. Operating system and some developers are allowed to use multitasking.

Comment: Lukas is correct, the O/S multitasks, it's just not functionality that's currently exposed to 3rd party apps. The platform could provided this feature, it just doesn't currently.