# A way to take screenshot of the WP7 app I develop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone

I want to take a screenshot of the WP7 app I'm developing. Is there a way to take a panorama full view of the app?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to take a screenshot in Windows - see this closed post for related info:

> [Take a screenshot on Windows Phone 7](https://superuser.com/questions/216092/take-a-screenshot-on-windows-phone-7)

This post talks about how to get the 'Panorama' shots like above in WP7:

> https://superuser.com/questions/194143/how-do-you-get-those-panorama-screenshots

Basically, you'll have to take the screenshots one at a time, and then stitch them together in Photoshop or Paint.NET, or something of the like.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been following for panorama screenshots:
http://www.markusegger.com/blog/Development.aspx?messageid=68e6dfd4-c761-4218-ba83-cf28ca2a8264